# I need to get the id of the dynamically generating button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

From this code it creates dynamic buttons accodring to a given value from another layout. I need to get the id of that and add another button (if dynamic button clicks then I need to add another button dynamically).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < value1; i++) {
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsIButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                ((int) ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ibutton = new ImageButton(HomePage.this);
            ibutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);

            ibutton.setLayoutParams(paramsIButton);
            paramsIButton.topMargin = -70;
            paramsIButton.leftMargin = 370;
            paramsIButton.bottomMargin = 30;
            ibutton.setId(i);

            ibutton.getPaddingBottom();
            ibutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            ibutton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            rR.addView(ibutton);

         }
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: I'm creating a unit to handle bulbs and fans. I'm dynamically creating a unit including the number of bulbs and fans the user selects. I have completed that part successfully! my problem is once a user is at the dynamically created unit's page if user clicks a button another bulb should be created. I can't do that part because I don't know how to identify whether the user clicked that button to add. Please help me! This is really important for me

Comment: Edit your question with that information so future users see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly from the additional information you provided on your comment, you need to know when a user clicked on a button. You could set an OnClickListener to your button.

```
// Somewhere in your activity . . .

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
         // The button is clicked! Do whatever you want.
      }
    });
}

// ...
// Rest of the code
// ...
```

Of course, you should replace `R.id.button1` with your button's id.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you need to add an onClickListener for the dynamically added button.

Make your class implement OnClickListener and then add a listener for the dynamic button:

```
ibutton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and add an onClick Listener within your class:

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
      // do something with this ID
      v.getId()
   }
```

I don't know how you keep track of the bulbs and fans, I'd hope you don't do it via the UI elements alone.  I'd probably do it a bit differently, creating a data structure to track the bulbs and fans and attach the specific bulb or fan object to the UI element as a tag.

Comment: Thanx a lot! Setting the onClickListner() worked for me! Thanx for your help!